# Intel XDK + Cordova background app refresh

Tags: android, ios, cordova, intel-xdk

I'm looking into developing a cross-platform mobile app using Intel XDK and Cordova.

The scenario is like this:

1. Every *n* minutes (e.g. *n*=5) check a specific URL for updates.
2. If there are any updates, show or increment the badge on the app icon.

Before you say *"use push notifications!"* let me explain a bit more. The app I'm building will use a third-party API. Every user should keep a state of what's been seen / not seen. If I were to use push notifications I'd have to build my own backend and API that consumes the third-party API, store the state for every user and send push notifications on every update. That does seem like a major overhead.

For such a scenario iOS has 'background app refresh' since version 7. I would like to use this, but not sure how to.

So, what I would like to know is:

- **Can I use the background app refresh functionality through Intel XDK / Cordova and how?**
- **How would this work for Android devices?**

Comment: I remember I read something about background app refresh. It must be possible and somewhere in the XDK there's a button which allows you to choose to run the app in the background or not. I don't know how you can do the refreshing every 5 seconds/minutes or how to do that with an API, but I know the XDK does have a feature which supports something like this.

Comment: There is a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239681/background-notification-https-github-com-katzer-cordova-plugin-local-notifi check if the github code solve your problem