# Background Notification ( [https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications]) in XDK (xdk cordova build "Android" does not build)

Tags: background-process, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk, localnotification, background-service

Which Background notification plugin is available for xdk?
I tried to build an app with the below plugin and The build failed.
 **Error: Plugin "myBackgroundNotification" failed to install.**

What's wrong with XDK cordova build?
Or what's wrong with the plugin and the id?

The plugin-> [https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git] 
The plugin-ID->[de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification ]
from this link-> [https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications]

Please, help me.
 Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It works  :D

from master 
That one does NOT build: [https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git]

stable version 
That one does build: **de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification**

Comment: When you say "_That one does build: de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification_" do you mean the one in the Cordova plugin registry works, but using the git repo does not?

Comment: I mean that the stable version works and the master version does not work/build in XDK. 
The stable plugin version used in cordova plugin registry is->: **de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification@0.7.6** but
I didn't use it. I used this one -> **de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification** without **@0.7.6** as repo-url and id.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Plugin ID: **de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification** 
Check Plugin is located in Cordova Registry

It works. For some reason the plugin in GIT repository does not work.